# Changing JPEG compression depending on image size

Tags: filters, images

Short. I want ''large' images compressed by 90%, and 'medium' to be by 60%. Has many af you know, sometimes larger images suffer from high compression, but other small images don't.

This function allows to resample all the jpg images

```
function custom_jpg_compression($args) {
    return 90;
}
add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'custom_jpg_compression');
```

How to filter by image size?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### A very *special* filter

The `jpeg_quality` filter is a *really* special one: It gets used in three different cases and you've to use the second argument to determine, *if* you want to use the filter or not.

### Don't let it do everything

The main problem for such a *special* filter is, that it may fire for later actions, if you ain't remove it - allow it to run after the first check. So we need to get another filter inside `wp_save_image_file()` to check if we want to alter the compression or not. To disable it for another save process, we remove it right before altering the compression.

### The kool kid

The really odd thing is, that WP uses a default compression of 90% (which is 10% reduced quality) for **every** save process. This means, that every time you upload/crop/edit an image, you reduce its quality... which is a pain for images that aren't the best, when you upload them (test it with an image containing a lot of red with a high contrast background). **But**... The really neat thing is, that you can change this behavior. So you want to change the compression, but **get increased quality** - much better than core allows- at the same time.

```
/**
 * Alter the image compression, depending on case
 * 
 * @param  int $compression
 * @param  string $case
 * @return int $compression
 */
function wpse58600_custom_jpg_compression_cb( $compression, $case )
{
    global $size_switch;

    // Should only fire once - don't leave it in for later cases
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Alter the compression, depending on the case
    switch ( $case )
    {
        case( 'edit_image' ) :
            // We only add the compression, if the switch triggered,
            // which means, that the size is smaller, than set in the main function.
            // 60 is the percentage value, that gets added as compression to the smaller images.
            $compression = $size_switch ? 60 : 100;
            break;

        case( 'image_resize' ) :
            // Better leave it on 100% for resize
            $compression = 100;
            break;

        case( 'wp_crop_image' ) :
            // Better leave it on 100% for crop
            // We already compressed it on the camera, the desktop/handheld device 
            // and the server previously. That's enough so far.
            $compression = 100;
            break;
    }

    return $compression;
}

/**
 * Alter the compression for JPEG mime type images
 * Checks for a specific min size of the image, before altering it
 * 
 * @param  string $image
 * @param  int $post_id 
 * @return string $image
 */
function wpse58600_custom_jpg_compression( $image, $post_id )
{
    global $size_switch;
    $size_switch = false;

    // Define the size, that stops adding a compression
    $trigger_size = 641;

    // Get the sizes
    $size_x = imagesx( $image );
    $size_y = imagesy( $image );

    // Add the filter only in case
    if ( $trigger_size < $size_x )
    {
        $size_switch = true;
    }
    add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'wpse58600_custom_jpg_compression_cb', 20, 2 );

    return $image;
}
add_filter( 'image_save_pre', 'wpse58600_custom_jpg_compression', 20, 2 );
```

**EDIT:** After a short discussion with @toscho, he pointed out, that the whole callback could be reduced to the following:

```
function wpse58600_custom_jpg_compression_cb( $compression, $case )
{
    // Should only fire once - don't leave it in for later cases
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    return ( $GLOBALS['size_switch'] && 'edit_image' === $case ) ? 60 : 100;
}
```

As I pulled the code out of a plugin I'm currently working on, I needed the `switch` to add settings in. I also have to note, that I don't use the `global` in my plugin, as it's an OOP approach. The code you can read ↑ above, is mainly reduced and altered code from the plugin, that has some minor left overs and is meant to be *explanatory* for later readers and still works. If you want to use it as plugin, you can do some optimization depending on your personal use case.

---

### Notes:

From some investigation on the different tasks, there are, I noticed, that multiple `$case`s get triggered on the following steps:

- Rotate: `edit-image` » `image-resize` (the later 1× for any any size you choose - Thumbnail, etc.)
- Mirror: `edit-image` » `image-resize` (--"--)

This means, that the filter callback for `jpeq_quality` will trigger 2× for rotating/mirroring an image and +1× for any additional size you add. So if you got less than 100%, it will reduce the quality twice. I did a lot of research on this topic, but I'm still not completely sure, what exact functions cause this behavior.

Comment: Ups you got me, print_r/var_dump doesn't work. How can I output that?

Comment: Use `echo '<pre>'.var_export( $image, true ).'</pre>';`. Put an `exit;` after it, so it doesn't get skipped with reloading the page, etc.

Comment: damn, lost in the woods - I can't see where it prints. I have that code before the return $image;

Comment: Add it right at the beginning of the `wpse58600_custom_jpg_compression()` function.

Comment: Edit image: the image is not shown.
Scaling the image: says "Missing argument 2 for wpse58600_custom_jpg_compression()" an then "NULL".
If var_export prints something, I can't find it.

Comment: Ehm, yea. I forgot to specify priority & argument counter for the filters. Try it again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4137/discussion-between-darkghosthunter-and-kaiser)

Comment: After push de **edit image**, and setting a scale, got this: 
 `resource(161, gd) `
 `boolean true `

Comment: @DarkGhostHunter Try the update.

Comment: It works, but it only compress it after editing the image inside the built-in editor. When, for example, I put `$compresssion = 1` to `image_resize` and `wp_crop_image`, the autogenerated thumbnails sizes remain the same high quality.

I accepted the answer anyway. [Posted a follow up here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58791/autogenerated-thumbnail-compression-depending-on-size).