# Autogenerated Thumbnail compression depending on size

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images, compression

This is a follow up to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58600/changing-jpeg-compression-depending-on-image-size), in witch the jpg compression is altered depending on what WP's built-in image resulting image size returns. While it may work for most of the people, i'm looking for a more discrete and automatic approach. And that is altering the  `wp_create_thumbnail` i think.

The point is this: How to alter the JPG compression of autogenerated thumbnails for an uploaded image? For example, images below 400px width at 60%, and between 401px~100px width at 80%.

Comment: Not sure this follow up is valid, but let's get into comments here, until we're done. `wp_create_thumbnail()` has `image_save_pre` as its first filter, so it should already work.

Comment: It works if I revert to the old code (hooking directly to jpeg_quality). wp_create_thumbnails is [this](http://pastebin.com/kQCkTtmr).

Comment: I know what `wp_create_thumbnail()` is. Currently code _is hooking directly_... `wp_create_thumbnail()` is just there to determine, _if_ hooking is _needed_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'm looking for a more discrete and automatic approach. And that is altering the `wp_create_thumbnail` i think.

And that is where you'd be wrong.  Here is the entire code for `wp_create_thumbnail()` from core:

```
function wp_create_thumbnail( $file, $max_side, $deprecated = '' ) {
    if ( !empty( $deprecated ) )
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '1.2' );
    $thumbpath = image_resize( $file, $max_side, $max_side );
    return apply_filters( 'wp_create_thumbnail', $thumbpath );
}
```

This function, on its own, doesn't do much.  Instead, if you need to change anything, it would be [`image_resize()`](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/media.php.source.html#l395) ... but changing the core function is still the wrong way to do this.

### Why Not Change Core

Changing a core file is usually frowned upon by mainstream developers.  If you change core and don't resubmit your changes to the project, you're left with a forked version of WordPress - the next time an update is released, you'll have to re-edit core files after you update to maintain your new functionality.

In many cases, the changes you want to make to core only apply to a handful of people - typically just you.  Unless the changes will benefit a majority of WP users, any core changes outside the scope of the current development cycle will usually be tabled for later or left in Trac with a "wontfix" resolution.

What works for *just* you or *just* me doesn't belong in the core project - it belongs in a plugin.

### The Right Way

The right way to change things up is to create your own version of `image_resize()` in a plugin.  Then build your own `my_create_thumbnail()` function that fits the following:

```
function my_create_thumbnail( $file, $max_side ) {
    return apply_filters( 'wp_create_thumbnail', my_image_resize( $file, $max_side, $max_side ) );
}
```

This function has the same signature as `wp_create_thumbnail()` and fires the same filters, so it can be used as a one-to-one replacement of the original function in all of your other plugin and theme scripts.

Comment: bounty accepted. I will have to do that to ensure images are compressing nicely.